# What is the differenc between Person and Account variables

Tags: remix, struct

What is the difference between Person and Account?

```
struct Account {
    address addr ;
    uint balance ;
}

Account[ ] public accounts;

function applyInterest () public returns ( uint ) {
    for ( uint i = 0; i < accounts . length ; i++) {
        // apply 5 percent interest
        accounts [i]. balance = accounts [i]. balance * 105 / 100;
```

& Person is:

```
Person[] public people;

uint256 public peopleCount;

struct Person {
    string _firstName;
    string _lastName;
}

function addPerson(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName) public {
    people.push(Person(_firstName, _lastName));
    peopleCount += 1;
}
```

If I use:
`People[0] .push(…..)`, I am getting syntax error on Remix IDE.

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using `People`, while the name of your variable is `people`.

Second, you can call `push` on an array, but you are trying to call it on an array element.

In short, replace this:

```
People[0].push(...);
```

With this:

```
people.push(...);
```

Comment: Why is people[0].push giving syntax error? On the other hand, I can use accounts[i].balance? what is the difference between Account[ ] & Person[ ]? Why I can't use '[ ]' brackets with people?

Comment: @zak100: Did you bother to read the answer? It refers to each one of these question!!! The `push` keyword is a built-in method in Solidity, which you can call on an array, **not on an array element**. It has no correlation whatsoever with `.balance`, which in your case is a reference to a field in the `Account` structure, so there is absolutely no room for comparison here.

Comment: Thanks for your information about push. I  verified by appending a balance field in the struct .